# Does it make sense to specify a "serialVersionUID" long in an abstract class?

Tags: java

Let us suppose that we've got the abstract class `Foo` that should be serialisable.

```
public abstract class Foo implements java.io.Serializable
{
      ...
}
```

Would it make sense to add an unique serial version identification `long` to it? If that is the case, should you add a `protected` modifier to it or should it stay `private`?

Comment: Or remove it altogether as it makes no sense there. Every `class` to be serialized should have its _own_ `serialVersionUID ` which **must** be a `private static final long`.

Comment: Actually, "must" is too strong.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java#ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All classes who extend the `Displayable` class require their own `serialVersionUID` long. Wouldn't it be better to add a protected or even public modifier to it?

No.  The `serialVersionUID` variable is only relevant to the serialization of instances of the class.  How this is done is purely an implementation detail for the class itself.  Exposing the variable to other classes is breaking abstraction ... albeit in a way that is hard to "exploit".

Or, to flip the question around, what would be *achieved* by making the variable more visible?  Can you think of anything apart from the serialization mechanism and the class that could make use of the variable?   (Certainly, it wouldn't in any way enforce the aforementioned requirement on `Displayable` classes.)

---

For what it is worth:

- The serialization mechanism uses reflection to access the `serialVersionUID` variable.
- The serialization mechanism will work irrespective of the variable's visibility.  It only requires that the field is `static` and `final`.   So if you wanted or needed your classes abstraction to "leak" the `serialVersionUID` ... that would work.
- The code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java#ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID%28java.lang.Class%29